# How can I create n number of files in python?

Tags: python, image, file

say user gives a number n=3
then I have to create 3 files dynamically. How will I do that? What can be the names of those files. Specifically I want n number of .jpg file created.

Comment: What kind of name do you *want* the files to have?

Comment: any name. say a.jpg,b.jpg...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an image stored in some format (maybe base 64 string?) already, you can do something like:

```
n = raw_input("Number of files: ")
image_list = ... # your logic for the image data here
n = int(n)
for i in range(n):
    image = open("image" + str(i) + ".jpg", "w")
    image.write(image_list[i])
    image.close()
```

For clarification, `w` means write to `filename` (overwriting its contents). If you want to append to a file instead, use `a`.

Edit: removed my wrong explanation on `+`

Comment: Your explanation of the `'+'` modes is incorrect. All `'w'` modes work to create a new file, though they'll happily truncate an existing file if there is one (use `'x'` if you want an existing file to be an error). The `'w+'` mode is special because it lets you seek back into the file after you've written to it and reread the data. Since you're not doing any reading, plain old `'w'` mode is probably the most appropriate.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tan. Solved my purpose. I am pretty new to file handling.
Thanks to @Blckknght too..

Answer (score 0):

```
num=input("enter no of files to be created:")
items =[]
for i in range(1,(int(num)+1)):
    items.append(i)
for item in items:
    open("%s_file.txt" % item, "a").close()
```

Comment: #this also works#
    num=int(input("enter no of files to be created:"))
    for item in range(1,(num+1)):
          open("File %s.pptx" % item, "a").close()

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can edit your answers and don't have to use the comments to add further points.