# How to have an integer in a filename (python)

Tags: python, string-formatting

I am making a code that will create textfiles equal to a number they entered, all named after them. So far i have this

```
name = input("Enter your name")  
num = input("Enter a number")  
x = 0
for i in range(1,num):
   x = x+1
   file = open(name(x) , "w+")
   lines = ("hi" , name)
   file.writelines(lines)
file.close()
```

but the name 'name(x)" won't work as a variable name, are there any ways of having variable names like x1, x2, x3 ect with an inputted number?

Comment: input treats them as strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create n number of files in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194886/how-can-i-create-n-number-of-files-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use formatting:

instead of `name(x)` you have to format a string:

```
"{0}{1}.txt".format(name, x)
```

the variable `name` will be placed on the `{0}` placeholder, the variable `x` will be placed on the `{1}` placeholder.

this means that if `name == "Answer"` and `x = 42`, the file name will be `Answer42.txt`

the formatting can be in any way you want:

```
"File_{1}_{0}_number{1}.txt".format(name, x)
```

will become: `File_42_Answer_number42.txt`;

or for example your `line` variable could be:

```
line = "Welcome {0}, How are you? you have opened {1} file until now!".format(name, x)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to do

```
file = open(name + str(x) , "w+")
```

or

```
file = open('{}{}'.format(name, x) , "w+")
```

In the first line, the `+` operator concatenates name (which is a string) with `str(x)`. The conversion to string is necessary.

In the second line, `format` does the conversion automatically.

You could rewrite the whole loop without x:

```
name = input("Enter your name")
num = input("Enter a number")

for i in range(1, int(num)):
   with open('{}{}'.format(name, i) , "w+") as file:
       lines = ('hi', name)
       file.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the  integer `x` to string:

```
name = input("Enter your name")  
num = input("Enter a number")  
for i in range(1,num):
   file = open(name + str(i) , "w+")
   lines = ("hi" , name)
   file.writelines(lines)
   file.close()
```

Comment: You should get rid of the `x`. We already have `i` with the same value. And `file.close()` should be part of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
name = input("Enter your name")  
num = input("Enter a number")  
x = 0
for i in range(1,int(num)):
   x = x+1
   file = open(str(x), "w+")
   lines = ("hi" , name)
   file.writelines(lines)
file.close()
```

Should do the trick. the `str()` wrapper around `x` in `open()` may even be necessary (I can never remember if something autoconverts to str or not). Furthermore, you had something strange going on in that line with `name(x)`. You haven't defined `name()` to be a function so it should have been giving you a big error.

`input()` returns a string, as user5173426 said in the comments. You have to explicitly cast it as an `int` with `int()` in order to perform numerical operations on it (`range()` expects a number, it does not cast strings to `int`).

Furthermore, you are defining `lines` to be a tuple of two strings. You may consider changing it to `lines = "hi" + name` or even `lines = f"hi {name}"`. I don't think you're going to get the output you're expecting in this case.